# secondaryTextColor in custom styles not work

Tags: java, android

This is my main xml layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="00dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottomNavigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="?attr/myBackgroundColor"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_items"
            app:itemTextAppearanceActive="@color/colorAccent"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_nav_color"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_nav_color"/>

    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:itemTextColor="?attr/myTextColor"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and my styles

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

</style>



<style name="brightTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#1976D2</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="myBackgroundColor">#FBFCFC</item>
    <item name="myEtBackgroundColor">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="myCardBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="myTextColor">#808080</item>
    <item name="myTintColor">#000000</item>
    <item name="myButtonColor">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="myHintTextColor">#B3808080</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWindowBackgroundDay</item>
</style>



<style name="darkTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212121</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#000000</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">#555</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="myBackgroundColor">#424242</item>
    <item name="myEtBackgroundColor">#606060</item>
    <item name="myCardBackground">#212121</item>
    <item name="myTextColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="myTintColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="myButtonColor">#2196F3</item>
    <item name="myHintTextColor">#B3FFFFFF</item>

    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorWindowBackgroundNight</item>
</style>
```

the problem is, I cannot use `<item name="android:textColorSecondary">#555</item>` neither in bright or dark mode because I get this error:

`2019-11-21 12:35:29.663 6291-6320/pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug E/libc: Access denied finding property "vendor.debug.prerotation.disable"
2019-11-21 12:35:29.796 6291-6291/pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug E/lenotepad.debu: Invalid ID 0x00000000.
2019-11-21 12:35:29.798 6291-6291/pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug, PID: 6291
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug/pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2956)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3091)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:866)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:67)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2936)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3091)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:280)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6748)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:216)
2019-11-21 12:35:29.798 6291-6291/pl.jawegiel.simplenotepad.debug E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1031)
        at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:651)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:67)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.createDefaultColorStateList(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:467)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.<init>(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:101)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationMenuView.<init>(BottomNavigationMenuView.java:86)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:123)
        at com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
            ... 30 more`
.

What should I do? I'm trying to be able to change secondary text color but unfortunately it does not work. If I remove both BottomNavigationView and Navigation view from my layout everything works.

Comment: Use the material components 1.1.0-beta02 and use a Material Components Theme

Comment: How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I need to pass resource from @colors instead of raw string.